# Get X, Y coords from private and public from AsymmetricKeyParameter

Tags: bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

```
public class EccGenerator
{
    public AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GenerateKeyPairs(int keySize)
    {
        ECKeyPairGenerator gen = new ECKeyPairGenerator("ECDSA");
        KeyGenerationParameters keyGenParam = new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), keySize);
        gen.Init(keyGenParam);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = gen.GenerateKeyPair();
        return keyPair;
    }

    public static void  PrintPublicX_Y(AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey)
    {
        ECPublicKeyParameters key = (ECPublicKeyParameters)publicKey;
        string X = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UrlBase64.Encode(key.Q.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
        string Y = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UrlBase64.Encode(key.Q.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
        Console.WriteLine(X + "--" + Y);
    }

    public static void PrintPrivateX_Y(AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey)
    {
        ECPrivateKeyParameters key = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)privateKey;
        string D = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UrlBase64.Encode(key.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
        string X = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UrlBase64.Encode(key.Parameters.G.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
        string Y = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UrlBase64.Encode(key.Parameters.G.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned()));
        Console.WriteLine(X + "--" + Y);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EccGenerator ecc = new EccGenerator();
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = ecc.GenerateKeyPairs(256);
        PrintPublicX_Y(pair.Public);
        PrintPrivateX_Y(pair.Private);
    }
}
```

The problem here is the X in public and private are not identical, also the same with the Y, how can I get the right x and y and D for private

I am using Bouncy Castle C#

Comment: The code does not compile, it is full of bugs, so no repro is possible. Please fix these bugs first.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edit it, just include the Bouncy Castle

Comment: G is the base point. The public key is obtained by multiplication with the private key, i.e. replace `key.Parameters.G` with `key.Parameters.G.Multiply(key.D).Normalize()`.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Can you post an answer to vote for it ;)

Comment: Sure, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public key is obtained by multiplying the base point G with the private key D. The result has generally to be normalized (the latter takes care of the transformation of the projective coordinates, which are used for performance reasons, into the affine coordinates, for details see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47079)).

Therefore, in `PrintPrivateX_Y()` the expression `key.Parameters.G` must be replaced by `key.Parameters.G.Multiply(key.D).Normalize()`.

The following alternative code:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
using System;
...
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = GenerateKeyPairs(256);

ECPublicKeyParameters publicKeyParams = (ECPublicKeyParameters)pair.Public;
ECPoint publicKey = publicKeyParams.Q;
PrintKey(publicKey);

ECPrivateKeyParameters privateKeyParams = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)pair.Private;
ECPoint publicKeyViaPrivate = privateKeyParams.Parameters.G.Multiply(privateKeyParams.D).Normalize();
PrintKey(publicKeyViaPrivate);
```

with

```cs
public static void PrintKey(ECPoint ecPoint)
{
    string X = Hex.ToHexString(ecPoint.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned());
    string Y = Hex.ToHexString(ecPoint.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned());
    Console.WriteLine(X + " -- " + Y);
}
```

and the (static) `GenerateKeyPairs(int keySize)` posted in the question shows, using the hexadecimal representation, that both public keys are identical as expected.

Comment: Should I normalize the D or let it with no change, also how to obtain The "kid" (key ID) parameter? Thanks @Topaco

Comment: The private key is a number and not a point, so there is no normalization in the above sense (technically key.D is not an `ECPoint` but a `BigInteger` for which there is no `Normalize()` method).

Comment: A kid is not mentioned anywhere in the question, so I can only speculate what you mean. Possibly the kid in the context of a JSON web key. The kid is a unique ID for the key, e.g. a UUID, [here](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwk-generation#ec). But this is definitely a new question and outside the scope of this question. Therefore, if you need more information, please post a new question on SO with a more detailed description of the problem. Thanks.